# Error al conectarse por SSH en Python con Mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, ssh

Al conectarme por ssh a mi base de datos en mysql tengo el siguiente código:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('miBaseDeDatos.com', 22),
        ssh_username='userSSH', ssh_password='passSSH',
        remote_bind_address=('miBaseDeDatosMysql.com', 3306)
    ) as tunnel:
        conn= mysql.connector.connect(
            user='userMySQL', password='passMySQL',
            host='127.0.0.1', port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
            database='mibasededatos'
        )
```

Pero cuando hago:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Me da el siguiente error:

OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: has probado haciendo algoa asi: `cursor = conn.cursor()`?

Comment: ¿Dónde realizas la instanciación del cursor?¿Dentro o fuera del bloque with?

Comment: Si, edito de nuevo la pregunta. La instancia del cursor la realizo fuera del bloque with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('miBaseDeDatosSSH.com', 22),
        ssh_username='userSSH', ssh_password='passSSH',
        remote_bind_address=('miBaseDeDatos.com', 3306)
    ) as tunnel:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            user='userMySQL', password='passMySQL',
            host='127.0.0.1', port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
            database='miBaseDeDatos'
        )
        if(connection is not None):
            cur = connection.cursor()
            cur.fetchall()
            cur.execute(sql)
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            connection.commit()
        connection.close()
```